# How add_option for array in Wordpress plugin? (e.g. add "file" to list of "files")

Tags: php, wordpress

I want my plugin settings page to have a list of all the currently managed files and allow them to add a new file path. Like this:

**Imaginary Layout in Browser**

```
Files Managed:
    * /wp-content/plugins/myplugin/files/file1
    * /wp-content/plugins/myplugin/files/file1
    * /wp-content/plugins/myplugin/files/file1
Add New File:
    [File_Name]
    [submit]
```

How would I achieve this? Previously, I was simply submitting the page to `options.php` (the Wordpress built-in options handler) but this fully replaces that option, and does not allow adding another option.

The only *"solution"* I was able to come up with (which seems hacky) is to handle myself and do this:

```
/* They've submitted the new file to manage, so we're in a POST situation */

//Get the existing options
$existing = get_option( "managed_files" );

//First time (doesn't exist yet)
if ( $existing === false ) add_option( "managed_files", array( $_POST[ "filename" ] ) );

//Already exists
else
{
    //Add to current values
    array_push( $existing, $_POST[ "filename" ] );

    //Update Option
    update_option( "managed_files", $existing );
}
```

Is this the only way?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$existing = get_option( "managed_files" );

//First time (doesn't exist yet)
if ( empty($existing) ){
    add_option( "managed_files", array( $_POST[ "filename" ] ) );
}
//Already exists
else
{
    //Add to current values
    //array_push( $existing, $_POST[ "filename" ] );
    $existing = array_merge($existing, array($_POST[ "filename" ]));

    //Update Option
    update_option( "managed_files", $existing );
}
```

I am not sure about `array_push` but `array_merge` will work perfect.

Hope you get little help from this.